# Sanitize user input fields before wp_insert_post

Tags: custom-field, security, sanitization

I read how to sanitize, validate and escape text fields and I know [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#security) sanitizes all field using `wp_kses` except HTML tags.

However, I'm new to development and would like to be confirmed that I'm going to right place.

Now, I'm creating user submitting frontend form.

There are several input fields,

1) Post title, type: text, sanitize method I've used: `sanitize_text_field( $_POST['post_title'] )`

2) Post content, type: textarea, sanitize method I've used: None, because of allowed html tag, for example, `<h1>` or `<img>` I do not sanitize. `wp_insert_post` will sanitize tags except allowed html tags.

3) URL, type: URL, sanitize method I've used: `esc_url( strtok( 'url, '?' ));` //Strip query string and sanitize.

4) Coupon code, type: text, sanitize method I've used: `sanitize_text_field( $_POST['coupon'] )`

5) Price, type: text, sanitize method I've used: `sanitize_text_field( $_POST['price'] )`

6) Image file(Thumbnail) type: file, sanitize method I've used: `sanitize_file_name( $_POST['file']['name'] )`

7) Category, type: int, sanitize method I've used: None, but validate whether the value is int or not using `absint()`, or type setting `(int)`

Is there anything else that I have to concern more?

I would like to know the way to secure my website.

The formal document recommend to use `wp_strip_all_tags` in post title field, however, I just use sanitize_text_field. Actually, I don't know the difference between `wp_strip_all_tags` and `sanitize_text_field` exactly. `sanitize_text_field` has more security features than `wp_strip_all_tags`, but in the light of the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#security), `wp_strip_all_tags` is enough for sanitizing. Am I right?

Any tips are appreciated. Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If calling, [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/), it actually call an internal function [`_sanitize_text_fields()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_sanitize_text_fields/) and add a filter for override. So

First look at `_sanitize_text_fields()`, which actually do

- Checks for invalid UTF-8,
- Converts single `<` characters to entities
- Strips all tags <--------- including [`wp_strip_all_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/) here
- Removes line breaks, tabs, and extra whitespace
- Strips octets

That's mean if calling `sanitize_text_field()`, it already includes `wp_strip_all_tags()` in the task list.

It is a pretty safe and generic method to sanitize any text.

By referring to the source code, it is known that the following use wp_strip_all_tags()

- sanitize_user() including some special characters checking
- wp_trim_words()
- wp_html_excerpt()
- wp_setup_nav_menu_item()
- comment's wp_blacklist_check()
- send_recovery_mode_email()
  ... etc

Because `wp_strip_all_tags()` strips all tags including styles and script and its content.
So it is a very useful tools and good for making any custom solutions if needed.

And according to source code, IDs and http status code are being `sanitize` by absint().
So I think what you are doing is enough.